# jquery add remove class

Tags: jquery, class, addition

I have 4 anchors, I want to add a class of current to an anchor as it is clicked and remove the class from the other 3 at the same time. Here's my code. what am I doing wrong?

```
if ($("ul#thumb a").hasClass("current") {
    $("ul#thumb a").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
});
```

and my html looks like this:

```
<ul id="thumbs">
    <li>
        <!-- intro page navi button -->
        <a id="t0" class="active" name="t0">The Company</a>

        <ul class="navi">
            <li><a style="display:none"></a></li>
            <li><a id="t1" name="t1">The Brief</a></li>
            <li><a id="t2" name="t2">The Solution</a></li>
            <li><a id="t3" name="t3">The Result</a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Is it not removing the class or is it not adding the classes? Also, this doesn't look like the full amount of jQuery. You need some sort of `$('ul#thumb a').click(function() {...});` to wrap it.

Comment: @Topher I have amended my post to show my html

Comment: I've updated my answer to represent your HTML.

Comment: @jonathan I appreciate the help many thanks. What I am trying to achieve though is the btns named #t0, #t1, #t2 & #t3 in the above html have the active class applied when they are clicked not just #t0. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

By using event-delegation, we only bind one handler for all click events. When an anchor (other than the `.current` anchor) is clicked, we strip the `.current` anchor of its class, and make the clicked anchor the new current one:

```
$("#thumbs").on("click", "a:not(.current)", function ( event ) {
    $(".current", event.delegateTarget).removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
});
```

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson what does `e.preventDefault();` mean? +1 by the way

Comment: @c0mrade: It prevents the default action of the link.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you

```
$("a").click(function() {
  $('a').removeClass('current');
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#'+id).addClass('current');
});
```

Comment: Why are you mixing `$` and `jQuery`? You should choose one and stick with it.

Comment: sorry it was mistake.. You can use one